# d3js multi line chart not auto updating

Tags: d3.js

I created multi line chart using mbostok and d3noob as reference. https://gist.github.com/d3noob/d8be922a10cb0b148cd5.

I want it to refresh after 3 secs. When it refreshes, the first line disappers. 
Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 570 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;


// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

//var y = d3.scale.range([height, 0]);

var axisTimeFormat = d3.time.format.multi([
    [".%L", function(d) { return d.getMilliseconds(); }],
    [":%S", function(d) { return d.getSeconds(); }],
    ["%H:%M", function(d) { return d.getMinutes(); }],
    ["%H:%M", function(d) { return d.getHours(); }],
    ["%a %d", function(d) { return d.getDay() && d.getDate() != 1; }],
    ["%b %d", function(d) { return d.getDate() != 1; }],
    ["%B", function(d) { return d.getMonth(); }],
    ["%Y", function() { return true; }]
 ]);


// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(10);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.tsv("final_report_multi.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        //console.log(d.d);
        d.date = parseDate(d.tim);
        //d.date = '2016-07-10 22:20:10';
        //d.date=d.date
        d.close = d.count;
        //console.log(d.date);
        //console.log(d.close);

    });

//data=data.sort(function(a, b) {
 //               return d3.ascending(a.tim,b.tim);
 //           });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
    //y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.count; }));
    y.domain([0,500]);

 var color = d3.scale.category10();

 // Nest the entries by symbol
    var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.dept;})
        .entries(data);

    // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log(d.values)
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
            .attr("d", valueline(d.values)); 
    });


    // Add the valueline path.
  //  svg.append("path")
 //       .attr("class", "line")
 //       .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});



var inter = setInterval(function() {
                updateData();
        }, 3000); 


        // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
  d3.tsv("final_report_multi.tsv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.tim);
        d.close = d.count;
        console.log(d.date);
        console.log(d.close);

    });

        // Scale the range of the data again 
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
       //  y.domain([d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
        y.domain([0,100]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

     // Nest the entries by symbol
    var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.dept;})
        .entries(data);

    // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
        var svg = d3.select("body").transition();
        console.log(d.values)
        svg.select(".line")   // change the line
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", valueline(d.values)); 
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis)
    });

    // Make the changes
   //     svg.select(".line")   // change the line
   //         .duration(750)
   //         .attr("d", valueline(data));
  //      svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
  //          .duration(750)
  //          .call(xAxis);
  //      svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
  //          .duration(750)
  //          .call(yAxis);

    });
}


</script>

</body>
```

tsv file i used

```
dept    tim count
home    2016-10-06 23:15:44 220 
home    2016-10-06 23:40:44 150 
toys    2016-10-06 23:10:44 400
toys    2016-10-06 23:30:44 1000
```

Comment: hi, any help please?

Comment: Pleas provide a jsfiddle with your code and it will be easier to find the problem

Comment: Hi, If i use jsfiddle, i get error "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://jsfiddle.net/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."                                                              so now i used plunker and here is the link. http://embed.plnkr.co/jiNYjoPdZG2rdZRDEJj9/.  Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason that it dissapears is that you change the y-scale to [0,100] (hardcoded). And since the line goes from 400 to 1000 it will not be visible. Also, in your case `count` is a string, so when d3 compares `"400"` with `"1000"`, `"400"` will be the largest value. To fix this parse count as string.

So to fix your problem, remove

```
y.domain([0,100]);
```

And change

```
d.close = d.count;
```

To

```
d.close = parseInt(d.count);
```

Comment: Both these did not help.  Let me explain my issue again.  Initially both lines are displayed fine. The issue i have is that after transition, the first line for dept=home disappears.  In the update data section, Some how the nest function and data selected is not correctly fetching the first value. Its fetching the second set of rows for dept=toys

Comment: I tried the changes i wrote here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XlMklo4mnwS0LO6t7nlU For me both lines are visible in the begining, and both lines are visible after the transition.

Comment: Hi @cleared, Its interesting.  Initially blue line is showing for values 220 to 150 . Orange line is showing for values 400 to 1000(actually its not showing 1000).

Comment: after transition, blue line is showing 400 to 1000. orange line is showing 800 to not sure where?

Comment: When you update your data/lines, do you bind the new "home"-data to the "home"-line, and the new "toys"-data to the "toys"-line?

Comment: If i comment   the below lines , then its slightly better . it shows 400 to 1000 but 200 to 1000. Not able to understand where its coming from             //  svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
      //      .duration(750)
      //      .call(yAxis)

Comment: I think if i add the style in the transition, then it will work , let me try

Comment: .style("stroke", function() {
                return d.color = color(d.key); })